# How can I create multiple account in Azure AD B2C using single email account?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, multi-tenant

I need to create multiple user account in Azure AD B2C with same email address. To handle the user from multiple logins. Both will be considered as different users. My question is

1. Is it possible to create the user accounts in a single tenant itself?

   Or
2. Do I need to create multiple tenants for handle these scenarios?

Scenario with example

- Suppose my application is for Library.
- I have multiple login pages for that.
- I have created '**test@mail.com'** as an **admin** user and also created same as **reader**, this will be done by GraphQL API.
- if I logged in from **'library/admin'** this need access admin level APIs and if I logged in from **'library/reader'** it should only access reader level APIs.
- *If the user reset his password from the reader page. It should not be affect the admin login.*
- So we need to consider both as different user.

Suggestions are welcome.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For your first question:

> It's impossible to create the user accounts with same email address in a single tenant.

For your second question:

> Even if you create multiple tenants, it is also impossible to implement this requirement(multiple user accounts with same email address).

And I don't think there is any other way for this requirement.

Comment: If multiple tenants are created both users will be saved in different directory right. So how we can say it is not possible. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Hi @AthulyaRatheesh If we created two tenants. In one of the tenant we create a user account, it will be `xxx@abc.onmicrosoft.com`. And in the other tenant we create a user account, it will be `xxx@def.onmicrosoft.com`. As they are two tenants, so the `abc` and `def` can't be same.

Comment: If a user **'test@gmail.com'** created an account with 'Tenant 1' and also suppose to register another account under 'Tenant 2'. So he can login on both application using the same email as different user ?

Comment: @AthulyaRatheesh May I know the tenant 1 and tenant 2 you mentioned means azure ad tenant or azure ad b2c tenant ?

Comment: We are creating azure ad b2c tenants.

Comment: @AthulyaRatheesh Are your email address all gmail address ?

Comment: For single user it will be same domain.

Comment: @AthulyaRatheesh Could you please describe the specific scene of your requirement ? I will try to help you tomorrow because it will be off time.

Comment: Thank you, @HuryShen I have added the scenario in the question. Hope the scenario is clear.

Comment: @AthulyaRatheesh The solution provided by alphaz18 is a workaround, I also want to suggest you with this solution but if you have many types of email address, the page will show gmail login and facebook login and .... So I asked you if all of the email addresses are gmail. Anyway, it is a workaround which may help your problem, you can refer to this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-google) about it. But I think it is a solution which not be recommended in azure b2c.

Answer (score 0):

The only "trick" to do this that I know of, you can have the user sign up again using a social media account with the same email. eg. sign up with xyz@gmail.com (using gmail as a provider) then sign up with xyz@gmail.com as a local account, or facebook account. then you're using the "same" email address, sort of. so you can probably use that fact to fulfill your requirement.

Other than that, no you cannot sign up with the same email address with the same identity provider. multiple tenants won't help you either, because I don't know how you would plan on linking the application to multiple b2c tenants

Answer (score 0):

To get a more clarity on your question. Say your application is a portal for clinics,
Clinic X & Y use your application
[www.application.com/x](http://www.application.com/x)
[www.application.com/y](http://www.application.com/y)

And the doctor in clinic X register (Clinic X Admin add the user) with email **doc@gmail.com**
and the same doctor is also a staff of Clinic Y so there he gets added to the application with the same email (**doc@gmail.com**).
So with B2C how can I achieve this? I suppose this is the example of Multi tenancy.

1. With single B2C tenant account
2. With Multiple B2C tenant account for each clinic ?

does this give more clarity?

Comment: I think you're mixing authentication and authorization here.
Once, a user is authenticated, the user just gets different permissons/roles/claims AFTER authentication by the application. So, the app needs to check the context (clinic X or Y) and add corresponding role claims to the identity.
Of course, with SSO in both clinics you should name your claims somthing like "role_x" and "role_y".
An even better approach is to use subdomains like x/y.application.com so you can provide different sessions/cookies per "tenant"